# How to use findViewbyId in BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to use imageview in a method which is inside my BroadCastReceiver class but it gives me error "Cannot resolve findViewbyid" since i cannot use findViewbyId outside mainactivity.Any ideas how i can use "findViewbyId" in this method "onButtonSingleOrDoubleClickOrHold".I basically need to change the color of imageview when this method is called.

Below is my BroadCastReceiver class

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends FlicBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
protected void onRequestAppCredentials(Context context) {
    // Set app credentials
}

@Override
public void onButtonSingleOrDoubleClickOrHold(Context context, FlicButton button, boolean wasQueued, int timeDiff, boolean isSingleClick, boolean isDoubleClick, boolean isHold) {

    if(isSingleClick) {
       ImageView blueImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       blueImage.setColorFilter(0xff000000);
       }
```

And my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        FlicManager.getInstance(this, new FlicManagerInitializedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onInitialized(FlicManager manager) {
                manager.initiateGrabButton(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
    } catch (FlicAppNotInstalledException err) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flic App is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    FlicManager.getInstance(this, new FlicManagerInitializedCallback() {
    @Override
     public void onInitialized(FlicManager manager) {
         FlicButton button = manager.completeGrabButton(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (button != null) {
                    button.registerListenForBroadcast(FlicBroadcastReceiverFlags.CLICK_OR_DOUBLE_CLICK_OR_HOLD);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Grabbed a button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Did not grab any button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How many times you would post the same question?  It is 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

You can try casting context to Activity manually in your `onButtonSingleOrDoubleClickOrHold`:

```
if(context == null || !(context instanceof MainActivity))
    return;

AppCompatActivity yourActivity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
ImageView blueImage = (ImageView) yourActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: This crashes my app error msg (Unable to start receiver com.example.abdullah.myapplication.MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to your `ImageView` or to your `Activity` into your `MyBroadcastReceiver`. You can set it when you instantiate your `MyBroadcastReceiver` passing what you need to the constructor, so when you need to act on something you already have it  into your `MyBroadcastReceiver`.

You can decide if pass an `Activity` and then to inflate your `ImageView` or if pass directly your `ImageView`.

Another approach is to declare your `MyBroadcastReceiver` as an activity's inner or anonymous class so you can access your main activity's variables directly

Answer (score -1):

You could make a decision to make a static `Activity` object inside your MainActivity, and call it from the `BroadcastReceiver`. It is not a good practice since it might cause memory leaks. However if you really want to keep your method inside your BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public static MainActivity instance = null;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       this.instance = this;
   }
}
```

And then call:

```
ImageView blueImage = (ImageView) MainActivity.instance.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I suggest you to rethink about your code design, and maybe move the changing color function to your activity, and call that method from the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I cannot change the parameters as this method is from another library which i imported in this project

Comment: Good job copying my answer!

Comment: @abdullah check the new one

Comment: Having the same thought is not always copying @C0D3LIC1OU5

Comment: It is terrible idea which leads to Activity leak.

Comment: Thankyou @GiovanniTerlingen declaring static worked. but is it a good practice?

Comment: No it may cause a memory leak, you should rethink about your code design, like creating the method of changing the color inside your MainActivity, and not in BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: i tried casting activity to context but it crashes my app error (Unable to start receiver ... java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: @abdullah if it solved your question, please mark it as answer.